# Process Substitution For Each Array Entry, Without Eval

Tags: arrays, bash, process-substitution

I have an array of arbitrary strings, for instance `a=(1st "2nd string" $'3rd\nstring\n' ...)`.
I want to pass these strings to a command that interprets its arguments as files, for instance `paste`.

For a fixed number of variables, we could use process substitution

```
paste <(printf %s "$var1") <(printf %s "$var2") <(printf %s "$var3")
```

but that does only work if the number of variables is known beforehand.
For the array `a`, we could write something fairly safe like

```
eval paste $(printf '<(printf %%s %q) ' "${a[@]}")
```

Out of interest: Is there a way to process-substitute each of `a`'s entries without using `eval`? Remember that `a`'s entries can contain any character (except for `\0` because `bash` doesn't support it).

Comment: `printf %s "$var1"` and `"$var1"` are virtually equivalent; are these just placeholders for more complicated commands?

Comment: @chepner Maybe I'm wrong, but to me `printf` seems necessary. The only placeholders in this question are `paste`  and the values inside `a`. How would you emulate a file with the same content as `$var1` if not with `<(printf %s "$var1")`?

Comment: Oh, right, you want `$var1` as the *contents* of a (pseudo)anonymous file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is inspired by [rici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045686/6770384).
It resolves the possible name collision caused by namerefs, but requires the user to specify a delimiter that does not appear in the command to be executed. Nevertheless, the delimiter can appear in the array without problems.

```
# Search a string in an array
# and print the 0-based index of the first identical element.
# Usage: indexOf STRING "${ARRAY[@]}"
# Exits with status 1 if the array does not contain such an element.
indexOf() {
    search="$1"
    i=0
    while shift; do
        [[ "$1" = "$search" ]] && echo "$i" && return
        ((++i))
    done
    return 1
}

# Execute a command and replace its last arguments by anonymous files.
# Usage: emulateFiles DELIMITER COMMAND [OPTION]... DELIMITER [ARGUMENT]...
# DELIMITER must differ from COMMAND and its OPTIONS.
# Arguments after the 2nd occurrence of DELIMITER are replaced by anonymous files.
emulateFiles() {
    delim="$1"
    shift
    i="$(indexOf "$delim" "$@")" || return 2
    cmd=("${@:1:i}")
    strings=("${@:i+2}")
    if [[ "${#strings[@]}" = 0 ]]; then
        "${cmd[@]}"
    else
        emulateFiles "$delim" "${cmd[@]}" <(printf %s "${strings[0]}") \
                     "$delim" "${strings[@]:1}"
    fi
}
```

### Usage examples

```
a=($'a b\n c ' $'x\ny\nz\n' : '*')
$ emulateFiles : paste : "${a[@]}"
a b x   :   *
 c  y       
    z       
$ emulateFiles : paste -d: : "${a[@]}"   # works because -d: != :
a b:x:::*
 c :y::
:z::
$ emulateFiles delim paste -d : delim "${a[@]}"
a b:x:::*
 c :y::
:z::
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of how you can use recursion to set up an argument list one argument at a time. The technique is occasionally useful.

Using process substitution to turn text into a pipe is possibly not the optimal solution to the problem at hand, but it does have the virtue of reusing existing tools.

I tried to make the code reasonably general, but it's possible that some more adjustments would be need to made.

Bash 4.3 is needed for the nameref (although you could do it with a fixed array name if you haven't yet reached that version). Namerefs require caution because they are not hygienic; a local variable can be captured by name. Hence the use of variable names starting with underscores.

```
# A wrapper which sets up for the recursive call
from_array() {
  local -n _array=$1
  local -a _cmd=("${@:2}")
  local -i _count=${#_array[@]}
  from_array_helper
}

# A recursive function to create the process substitutions.
# Each invocation adds one process substitution to the argument
# list, working from the end.
from_array_helper() {
  if (($_count)); then
    ((--_count))
    from_array_helper <(printf %s "${_array[_count]}") "$@"
  else
    "${_cmd[@]}" "$@"
  fi
}
```

Example

```
$ a=($'first\nsecond\n' $'x\ny\n' $'27\n35\n')
$ from_array a paste -d :
first:x:27
second:y:35
```

Comment: Great idea, thank you! I used your approach to create a [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059311/6770384) without the possible name collision. However, both version are a bit long. I keep this question open to encourage people to find a better solution.

Comment: Yes, or `printf '%s' "${a[@]}" | pr -t${#a[@]}`... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

use eval and pass the strings [by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208432/10440128) (not by value)

```
a=(1 2 3)
d=":"
eval paste '-d"$d"' $(printf '<(echo -n "${a[%s]}") ' "${!a[@]}")
```

```
a=(1 2 3)
d=":"
paste -d"$d" <(echo -n "${a[0]}") <(echo -n "${a[1]}") <(echo -n "${a[2]}")
```

```
1:2:3
```

Comment: What is the benefit here, over the solution `eval paste $(printf '<(printf %%s %q) ' "${a[@]}")` already proposed in the question? Anyways, it seems you missed the essential part of the question: **without using eval**

Comment: passing the strings by reference needs less memory. this page is in search results for "bash pass multiple strings by process substitution", so a "proper" eval solution should be here too. looking at the complexity of the recursive solution, its just stupid to demand that "eval is bad"... eval can be bad when accepting dynamic user input, but that is not the case here

Comment: Right, the question is only about curiosity, not about practicality. Just because googling another similar question leads to this thread her (*at the moment!*), shouldn't justify posting answers that that ignore an essential part of the original question. How about you create a separate question and answer it yourself? I would be happy to upvote you there, and also prominently link your question in my question here.

Comment: *"reference needs less memory"* Thank you for clarifying. Now that you say it, it *seems* obvious. I could even *verify* it by running `seq 1e1000 1e1001 | head -n 1000 | /usr/bin/time -f '%M kB' bash -c 'mapfile a; eval cat ... | md5sum'` where the `...` part was **1.** `$(printf '<(printf %%s %q) ' "${a[@]}")` => 12236 kB **2.** `$(printf "<(echo -n \"\${a[%s]}\") " "${!a[@]}")` => 2724 kB

Comment: @milahu on rici's answer, there are not string passed as arguments, just *file descriptors* (as string, I agree, but it's small and reliable). There are no *multiple process substitution*, just simple *recursion*.

Comment: yeah. replacing a simple eval with 2 functions and global variables is just... not elegant. eval is only bad when accepting random user input, then its a security risk