# adding process substitutions to a command line with a loop in bash

Tags: bash

From the command line, I can use gsutil cat to pipe input into sox. Works perfectly. Here is the code that works from the command line:

```
sox <(gsutil -q cat gs://some-bucket/201808130800.wav) ./test-show.wav -t 
wav trim 0 10
```

However, in my bash script, it fails. I have tried numerous configurations. At the end of the day, sox complains about a bad filename. Same exact code runs from command line.

Here is the line of code. All variable are correct. If I use sox to work on local files, it works great.

```
sox $(for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @$base_time) +$i hours")
file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
echo -e "<(gsutil -q cat gs://somebucket/$file_name.wav)"
done) "$target/$show_name.wav -t wav trim $f_offset $run_time"
```

If I put an echo in front of the command, what prints on the screen is exactly what works from the command line. I can copy and paste the output to a command line and it works.

Here is the output:

```
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `gs://somebucket/201808130800.wav)': No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Addendum:

I got it almost working with:

```
gsutil cat "$(for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
  file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @$base_time) +$i hours")
  file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
  echo "gs://somebucket/$file_name.wav"
done)" | sox -V4 - $target/$show_name.wav trim $f_offset $run_time
```

Comment: ...indeed, that won't work. `<(...)` isn't text `sox` can parse, it's a shell process substitution directive. Expansion results, like text from `$(...)`, isn't parsed as shell code, so *no* substitutions -- not process substitution, not command substitution, not any other -- are honored there.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- `foo $(for ...)` has the exact same problem that `foo $bar` does, which is an issue that FAQ covers in detail.

Comment: ...that said, in terms of building an alternative that **will** work -- which version of bash are you targeting here? This is easiest with 4.1 or newer. And can we rely on targeting only an operating system with `/dev/fd` or `/proc/self/fd` available?

Comment: Here is the version I am using:
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: ...maybe this should be retitled to something like "adding process substitutions to a command line with a loop in bash"?

Comment: I retitled. I will search on different terms now that i understand more about what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: *nod*, np. And in the interim, I'm working on an answer; there are a few different approaches that can work here.

Comment: Please click "Add an Answer" to add your own answer, instead of editing it into the post. See [editing potential answers into questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319747) on [meta]; or [Add description of used solution - How?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298405)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Backstory: What's Going Wrong

The output of a command substitution (the `$(...)` syntax which encapsulates your `for` loop) isn't parsed as code by the shell; rather, it goes only through string-splitting (splitting on spaces, unless `IFS` has been changed) and glob expansion (substituting strings like `*.txt` with a list of matches) before being put directly on the command line to `sox`.

However, `<(...)` isn't a directive for `sox`; it's a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) directing *the shell* to put a filename which can be read from to retrieve the subprocess's output in that location on the command line before invoking `sox`.

You can dynamically generate filenames associated with the output of commands a few ways, as described below.

---

#### Approach 1: Use Named Pipes Instead

One of the easier things to do here is to build explicit (named) FIFOs rather than relying on process substitution to create anonymous ones:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/sox-pipes.XXXXXX") || exit

declare -a fifos=( )

cleanup() {
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
  kill "${!fifos[@]}"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
  file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @"$base_time") +$i hours")
  file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
  mkfifo "$tempdir/$file_name.fifo"
  gsutil -q cat gs://some-bucket/$file_name.wav >"$tempdir/$file_name.fifo" &
  fifos[$!]="$tempdir/$file_name.fifo"
done

sox "${fifos[@]}" ./test-show.wav -t
```

This approach can be retrofitted to work on any POSIX-compliant shell -- the use of arrays isn't strictly mandatory -- which means it also works on shells that don't support `<(...)` syntax at all.

---

#### Approach 2: Generate An `eval`-safe Command

The tricky thing about this is that it has to be done with great care to prevent data (like filenames) from being leveraged into shell injection attacks. Note the use of `printf %q` to escape data being substituted into the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cmdline=''
for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
  file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @"$base_time") +$i hours")
  file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
  printf -v piece ' <(gsutil -q cat gs://some-bucket/%q.wav) ' "$file_name"
  cmdline+="$piece"
done

eval "sox ${cmdline} ./test-show.wav -t"
```

---

#### Approach 3: Collect An Array Of File Descriptors

There are some tricky caveats here: The `gsutil` instances won't exit until *all copies* of their stdout descriptors have closed, which means they'll still be running after `sox` finishes until the shell closes its own copies.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.0.*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.1 required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

gsutil_fds=( )
for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
  file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @"$base_time") +$i hours")
  file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
  exec {gsutil_fd}< <(gsutil -q cat gs://some-bucket/"$file_name".wav)
  gsutil_fds+=( /dev/fd/"$gsutil_fd" )
done

sox "${gsutil_fds[@]}" ./test-show.wav -t

for fd in "${gsutil_fds[@]#/dev/fd/}"; do
  exec {fd}>&-                     # close the fifo so this copy of gsutil can exit
done
```

---

#### Approach 4: Use Recursion

...as described in [Process Substitution For Each Array Entry, Without Eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040310/process-substitution-for-each-array-entry-without-eval)

Comment: Thanks for the details. I just got it working by looking at if from the other end. Rather than pipe in to sox, I pipe out from cat to sox. When I have time, maybe I'll look at it again Here is the working code:

    gsutil cat "$(for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
    file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @$base_time) +$i hours")
    file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
    echo "gs://somebucker/$file_name.wav"
    done)" | sox -V4 - $target/$show_name.wav trim $f_offset $run_time

Comment: I like approach #2. I'll look at that later this evening as it fits what I feel is the correct scheme.

Comment: If you can pass a single instance of `gsutil cat` more than one URL, and if `sox` will permit multiple `wav` files to be concatenated into a single stream, either of those permits a much better answer than anything given here.

Comment: For example: `content=( ); for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @$base_time) +$i hours") file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M"); content+=( "gs://somebucket/$file_name.wav" ); done; gsutil cat "${content[@]}" | sox -V4 - "$target/$show_name.wav" trim "$f_offset" "$run_time"` is much safer/better practice (it'll work with names that have spaces in them; it'll work even if `IFS` is set to a value that contains numbers or other characters found in the names; etc).

Comment: Take a look through [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) -- you'll see that unquoted expansion (and the word-splitting and globbing stages it triggers) is one of the leading causes of surprising/unintended behavior in bash. Getting into habits that rely on that behavior is setting yourself up for problems.

Comment: Or even: `for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @$base_time) +$i hours") file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M"); gsutil cat "gs://somebucket/$file_name.wav"; done | sox -V4 - ...`, which is **much** cleaner, and doesn't require any process substitutions at all.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP, previously edited into the question:

> Here is the final solution that works. First, i changed from wav source files to raw PCM files to remove the 44 byte wav header. This makes cating seamless. Here is the one liner:
>
> ```
> gsutil -q cat $(for ((i=0; i<file_count; i++)); do
>   file_time=$(date "+%s" --date="$(date -d @$base_time) +$i hours")
>   file_name=$(date --date="@$file_time" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
>   echo "gs://somebucket/$file_name.raw"
> done) | sox -t raw -b 16 -c 2 -e signed-integer -r 48k -L - 
> $target/$show_name.wav trim $f_offset $run_time
> ```